# Tomcat7 fail to start on eclipse indigo

Tags: java, tomcat7

after declaring New Server in eclipse and run it .. tomcat 7 fails to start and print this in the console :

```
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Comment: do you have the jar servlet-api included in your classpath?

Comment: That method getSessionCookieConfig() is new in servlet-api 3.0 - you might have the wrong version as well.

Comment: My Work space is empty there is no projects.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted you probably have an older version of `servlet-api.jar` on your classpath. You can turn on verbose class loading (VM argument `-verbose:class`) to see which .jar file `javax.servlet.ServletContext` is getting loaded from. Tomcat 7 uses API version 3.0. In our (test) case we had version 2.4 on the classpath; excluding it in the test class path of the surefire plugin (we're Maven-based) worked, i.e. `<classpathDependencyExcludes>javax.servlet:servlet-api</classpathDependencyExcludes>`. Tomcat 7 then picked up its own, compatible version. If you need to have the .jar on the classpath you can get a compatible one with these Maven artifact coordinates `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1`.